# Raspberry connecting to WIFI with captive portal

Tags: authentication, raspberry-pi, wifi

Currently I have learned how to config my Pi to connect to the WIFI with or without a password, however when I wanna use the WIFI in, say a coffee house or a hotel, where the WIFI provided requires logging on a captive portal to get to use it, I know that with a browser it could be easy to do it since the login page appears right up as you open the browser, but how can I do it with my Pi through the command line?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not asking how to script repeatedly connecting to a certain captive portal (this could potentially be accomplished with curl), you probably want to use a text-based web browser like [Elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) or [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: I've tried elinks, but later I found out that does not support javscript on which the captive page requires, I followed the offical Elinks' manual, but not working. But I've found another way to login the captive which is using TightVNCServer installed on my PI and remote to it and login the captive. So problem solved! thanks for you help.